# how can i fix the unable to instantiate activity component info exception

Tags: java, android, image, slider, marquee

in my aplication i wanna to view a slide pictures as the marquee with the text view (put here with images instead of the text view ), i have this code already from the internet but at the run time i have a run time exception which is " unable to instantiate  activity componentinfo"
i try to fix the problem by right click on the project and then goes to properties then at java build path do some thing ,, and then clean the project but also i still have the same problem ,, i have been restarted the emulator and eclipse but also this isn't useful for me what must i do to run this code ??

this is my code:

```
            package com.example.marquee;

        import java.util.Timer;
        import java.util.TimerTask;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.Handler;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ImageView;

        public class AutoSlider extends Activity {

            public int currentimageindex=0;
            Timer timer;
            TimerTask task;
            ImageView slidingimage;

            int[] IMAGE_IDS = {R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.yt, R.drawable.yt,
                    R.drawable.s};

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

                // Create runnable for posting
                final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        AnimateandSlideShow();

                    }
                };

                int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

                int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

                Timer timer = new Timer();

                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {

                     mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

                }

                }, delay, period);

            }

            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
              }
               private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

                slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);

                currentimageindex++;

              }}
```

and this logcat :

07-29 15:21:03.790: W/Trace(1473): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-29 15:21:03.842: W/Trace(1473): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-29 15:21:03.842: D/AndroidRuntime(1473): Shutting down VM
07-29 15:21:03.890: W/dalvikvm(1473): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.marquee/com.example.marquee.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.marquee.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.marquee-1.apk
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.marquee.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.marquee-1.apk
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-29 15:21:03.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     ... 11 more

Comment: does activity_main.xml contains imageView1? Post the full stacktrace

Comment: Make sure your Activity is defined in the Manifest file. Please post Logcat trace as well

Comment: yeah my xml layout has an image view ,, and this is the main activity sure ut's in the manifest :(